# Inconsistency barcode results using ZBarReaderViewController in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, zbar-sdk

I am doing one iOS app in which I have to scan the barcodes . I have used ZBarReaderViewController for scanning the barcodes . Sometimes it is giving the result accurately but sometimes it is giving unknown value like this **&7&#,Ac9** .My Image is [image] My code is

```
 -(IBAction)scanBarCode:(id)sender
{
reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
     reader.readerDelegate = self;
     reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
    reader.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;  

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale >= 1136)
    [reader.readerView setScanCrop:(CGRect){ { 0.25, 0.08 }, { 0.07, 0.84} }];//.25
else
    [reader.readerView setScanCrop:(CGRect){ { 0.23, 0.08 }, { 0.09, 0.84} }];

 ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
 // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

 // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
 /*[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
 to: 0];*/

//swetha test
[scanner setSymbology: 0
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];
// Enable EAN 13
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_EAN13
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 1];
// Enable UPC-A
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_UPCA
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 1];
// Enable Code 128
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_CODE128
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 1];
 [self presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:nil];
 [reader release];
```

}

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
     [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
     ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
     for(symbol in results)
     // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
     break;

     // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
     serialnumber.text = symbol.data;

     // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
     //resultImage.image =
     //[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

     // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
     barcodeClicked = 0;

     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Please let me know if I am not clear . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

My imagepickerControll function is as follows:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*)reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info {
  @try {
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    for(id obj in results) {
      ZBarSymbol *symbol = obj;
      serialnumber.text = [symbol data];
    }
  }
  @catch (NSException *ex) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ex]
                                                delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
  }
  barcodeClicked = 0;
  [reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  
}
```

I would strongly recommend using try-catch and going through all the results, since it may interpret 2 different barcodes if they are close by, and parsing the object as ZBarSymbol.